# A way to calculate if the users score is matched to finale game score

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

im trying to know if the user guess is right, 
i made that noobi formula(a lot of if's)(formula is inside I3):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($E3:$E="","",IF($E3:$E=G3:G,Lists!$G$2,iferror(if(match($E3:$E,Lists!$E$1:$E$6,0),IFERROR(if(match(G3:G,Lists!$E$1:$E$6,0),Lists!$G$3,""),Lists!$G$4),""),IFERROR(if(MATCH(G3:G,Lists!$E$1:$E$6,0),Lists!$G$4,""),IF(OR($E3:$E="1 - 1",G3:G="1 - 1"),Lists!$G$4,if(G3:G="",Lists!$G$4,Lists!$G$3)))))))
```

[image: thats how it looks - IMAGE HERE]

i have games list (barsa vs madrid,etc.) it takes the "finale score" and "user guess score" and check how much points the user should get in that way: Lists!$E$1:$E$6 = 1 - 0, 2 - 0, 3 - 0, 3 - 2, 3 - 1, (and more, only the left side winning results) (i make that for online game that unlike football the optional finale scores are knowing(Best of 3,BO5,etc)).
so im taking the finale score check if its in the list and then check if user score in the list, if both there so he was right about the wining side same happens if both results are not at the list he still got the right team that won, also i have in the formula equaling the results so if its the same the user gets more points then just guessing the wining side, last obviously if he was wrong he gets 0 points and in the table i wanted it to look like minus so that's what i did "-". 
OK so here is the points behind the references : Lists!$G$2 - "5", Lists!$G$3 - "3", Lists!$G$4 - "-"

1. The code was right everything worked nicely and suddenly i found a bug, like u can see at the image, the 2nd Wrong should be "3" points, i could not find the bug myself so ill be happy for some help.
2. On the further ill probably add more sports types so ill have more scores types to handle, like basketball totally different type of scores, i need a direction, how i can do that? it can be from formula or script i can handle that just point me the way please.

hope i made everything clear, my English is not at it best so.. thanks for understanding.
hope my title is fine xD

Comment: Looks like its working and damn how much i can learn from that code, really appreciate your help! about the "users score" i think the best way is to give them namedRanges, what do you think? thats the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try I3:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E8=G3:G8,5,if(iferror(match(C3:C8,QUERY({C3:C8,SPLIT(E3:E8,"-"),SPLIT(G3:G8,"-")},"Select Col1 Where (Col2>Col3 and Col4>Col5) or (Col2<Col3 and Col4<Col5)",0),0)),3,0)))`

- IF E=G,return 5 points, else
- QUERY to select Teams(C) ,where win side was predicted correctly by user(G)
- IF Query results MATCH C column(Teams), return 3 points,else 0.

Comment: Dear |'-'|. if you can when you will have time, to add a draw option, if ill add soccer games 2 - 2, 3 - 3.. need to get 3 points, it was on the far far further but with your formula it will be very soon.. thanks..

Comment: I will try and let you know! appreciate your attitude.

Comment: OK i tried and came out with that: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E8=G3:G8,5,if(iferror(match(C3:C8,QUERY({C3:C8,SPLIT(E3:E8,"-"),SPLIT(G3:G8,"-")},"Select Col1 Where (Col2>Col3 and Col4>Col5) or (Col2<Col3 and Col4<Col5) or (Col2=Col3 and Col4=Col5)",0),0)),3,0)))  its works but i found a bug >.> the result is correct but its affect the next row somehow and i didn't figure why its happening, any suggestion? (the code is example of what i did, in the l3 cell i edited c3:c8 to c3:c and if c3:c="","",theFormula)  [Here you can see what is happening](https://image.ibb.co/nBE9E8/bug.jpg)

Comment: Emm.. i added anther IF, that if "your guess" empty  and "result" is not it will give him wrong automaticly and looks like its fixed the problame

Comment: Thanks again @I'-'I